# AWS Cloudformation Stack - Route Table Main

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to specify in the cloudformation stack template the when adding a route table and set it to main:yes?

On my current stack template there's always a route table associated with my VPC (Also created by the stack) that is set to main:yes but it's not specified route table on my stack template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

When a VPC is created, a 'Main' Route Table is automatically created, which will be the default route table for all subnets that do not have a Subnet Association specified.

It is not possible to create a subnet via CloudFormation that takes on this property.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create similar setup you need to write the whole stack for infra by yourself: VPC, Internet Gateway, Subnet and Route Table. Then you need to explicitly define RouteTableAssociation for the specific subnet and create a public route for the table. YAML example of such a setup

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Example
Resources:
  myInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "a_gateway"

  myVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default

  # Attach Internet gateway to created VPC
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: myVPC
      InternetGatewayId:
        Ref: myInternetGateway

  # Create public routes table for VPC
  myPublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "public_routes"

  # Create a route for the table which will forward the traffic
  # from the gateway
  myDefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref myPublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref myInternetGateway

  # Subnet within VPC which will use route table (with default route)
  # from Internet gateway
  mySubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: ""
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/25
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId:
        Ref: myVPC

  # Associate route table (which contains default route) to newly created subnet
  myPublicRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref myPublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref mySubnet
```

Template is not really short, but to accomplish this simple requirement you have to define everything explicitly.

> One way to protect your VPC is to leave the main route table in its
>   original default state (with only the local route), and explicitly
>   associate each new subnet you create with one of the custom route
>   tables you've created. This ensures that you must explicitly control
>   how each subnet's outbound traffic is routed.